# Rails: Custom built ban user functionality not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to ban a user, but it is not working as expected, probably because I have no clue what I am doing:

```
Routes:

      resources :users do
        collection do
          post 'ban'
        end
      end


class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def ban
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.admin?
      @user.banned = true
      @user.avatar = nil unless @user.avatar.nil?
      @user.banned_by = current_user.full_name
      @user.profile = nil unless @user.profile.nil?
      @user.save
      redirect_to current_user, notice: "User has been banned."
    end
  end
end
```

In my view:

```
<%= link_to "Ban User", ban_users_path(:id => @user.id), :method=>:post %>
```

For some reason, it passes the parameter "ban" and says cannot find user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes should be

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post 'ban'
  end
end
```

Member routes act on a member, so your request would look like `POST /users/1/ban` (user #1 being the member). Collection routes are for acting on the entire collection, i.e., `POST /users/ban`. Your helper should turn into into `ban_user_path(@user)`

Also I don't think you need to check if their avatar/profile is nil before setting them to nil. Just set them to nil, there is no need to check. If they are already nil, there is no harm done by setting them to nil again.